# laravel blade page is not displaying some data

Tags: php, laravel

i have a model called notification. this model is responsible for fetching data from the database. it has a static method which changes the data retrieved from the database to string value. if the data stored is 200, it changes it into 'up' otherwise into 'down'. i called this function in my blade page to display all the urls based on their status. that is, it will display the 'up', 'down' and 'not active' urls.  for some reason, it failed to display the up websites, for down and no active websites, it is doing fine.

this is my model: notification model

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Status;
use App\Notification;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Notification extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','website_url','email','slack_channel','check_frequency','alert_frequency','speed_frequency','active'];

    public function statuses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Status')->withPivot('values')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function status($s_type)
    {
        if (!in_array($s_type, ['speed', 'health'])){
            return false;
        }

        $o_status = Status::where('name', strval($s_type))->first();
        $o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
        ->select('values', 'created_at')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();

        if($o_response === null){
            return false;
        }

        return [
            'value' => $o_response->values,
            'timestamp' => $o_response->created_at
        ];
    }

    public function history($s_type)
    {
        if (!in_array($s_type, ['speed', 'health'])){
            return false;
        }

        $o_status = Status::where('name', strval($s_type))->first();
        $o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
        ->select('values', 'created_at')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();

        if($o_response === null || $o_response->count() === 0){
            return false;
        }


        $a_ret = [];
        $last = null;

        foreach ($o_response as $o_status) {
            if($last != $o_status->values) {
                $a_ret[] = [
                'value' => $o_status->values,
                'timestamp' => $o_status->created_at
                ];
                $last = $o_status->values;
            }
        }
        return $a_ret;
    }

    public static function health($resCode)
    {
        return intval($resCode) === 200 ? 'up' : 'down';
    }
}
```

and this is my blade page

```
 <tbody>
        @foreach($notes as $notification)
            <?php $notificationHealth = $notification->status('health'); ?>
            <?php $notificationSpeed = $notification->status('speed'); ?>
            @if ((is_null($active) || $notification->active == $active) && (empty($health) || ($health === 'down' && empty($notificationHealth['value'])) || $notificationHealth['value'] === $health))

                <tr> 
                    <td> {{ $notification->website_url }} </td>

                   @if($notificationHealth !== false)
                        @if(\App\Notification::health($notificationHealth['value']) == 'up')
                            <td> {{ \App\Notification::health($notificationHealth['value']) }} <span class="up"></span><br><span class="timestamp_green">{{  $notificationHealth['timestamp'] }}</span></td>.

                        @elseif(\App\Notification::health($notificationHealth['value']) == 'down')
                            <td> {{ \App\Notification::health($notificationHealth['value']) }}  <span class="down"></span><br><span class="timestamp_red">{{ $notificationHealth['timestamp'] }}</span></td>

                        @else
                            <td> {{ \App\Notification::health($notificationHealth['value']) }}  <span class="unsigned"></span><br><span class="timestamp_unsigned">{{ $notificationHealth['timestamp'] }}</span></td>

                        @endif
                    @else
                        <td> N/A <span class="unsigned"></span></td>       
                    @endif
```

apperciate for the help!

Comment: what output you getting in case of up or any error ?

Comment: no error at all just no table for the website which are 'up'. only i get tables for the down websites and not active websites

Comment: what's the output if you do `<?php dd($notification->status('health')); ?>` in your blade template, does it give anything?

Comment: if i put it at the top of the table i get this : array:2 [▼
  "value" => ""
  "timestamp" => Carbon {#258 ▶}
].......

Comment: if i put it under the first <td> . that whan the status is up. it give me this: array:2 [▼
  "value" => "200"
  "timestamp" => Carbon {#306 ▶}
]

Comment: and if i put it under the status down, after elseif statment, it gives me the following: array:2 [▼
  "value" => ""
  "timestamp" => Carbon {#258 ▶}
]